# I tried to run the application and It fails with required beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Description:

Field userRepository in com.rst.boot.services.impl.UserServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

This is my service class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserServices {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<UserDTO> findAllUsers() {
       List<UserDTO> allusers= userRepository.findAll();
       return allusers;
    }

    @Override
    public String saveUser(UserDTO userdata) {
        userRepository.save(userdata);
        return "Data saved";
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Leaning</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Springboot Demo App</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response .Where should I define this bean names 'entityManagementFactory'?

Comment: You need to show us the configuration class. Supposing you have configured everything correctly, Spring is asking to define the JPA EntityManagerFactory bean: `@Bean public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {...}`

Comment: I did add the UserServiceImpl.java  I'm new to Spring-boot can you please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your bootstrap class make sure you have the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation. If you have @SpringBootApplication, should be enough, since the latter is annotated with the first.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Second, make sure that UserRepository extends JpaRepository or CrudRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Last, check that you have the correct dependency in your maven or gradle configuration. E.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have done all the above but still gets the same error message

Comment: Try removing the hibernate and java persistence dependences. Leave only spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: Yeah, this helped. Dependencies were kind of overlapped